# password protected zip file in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

can Zippackage class be used to find content inside a password protected zip file,
if not can it be done without using any 3rd party api

Comment: You can do anything without using a "3rd party api" - by writing it yourself! If you don't feel like doing that, just use the 3rd party library...

Answer (score 3):

I don't think so.

I suggest you use SharpZipLib instead: http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/

Comment: is it possible without using any third party api

Comment: No.  The ZIP support in .NET is very limited, even the ZipPackage stuff is not intended to offer full-blown ZIP support.  SharpZipLib is open-source "free" software that is widely used and I've used it many times without problem.

Comment: thanks for replying daniel 
can we find whether a zip file is password protected or not without using 3rd part api

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the answer to that.   can only suggest you try opening a passordprotected ZIP with ZipPackage and see what happens.  If you get an exception, the answer is yes, if you just get corrupt data, the answer is no.

Answer (score 2):

I'd also recommend [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/).